# Meanings of grammatical terminology to describe verbs

Tags: verbs, terminology, tenses

I am new to this site. A recent answer used two terms I am not familiar with, 'indicative' and 'preterite'. I cannot ask the expert at the chatroom I usually frequent; **I am** the expert on such questions there.
May I describe the way I believe verbs are classified and then ask questions about the best terminology to use?
Verbs, when used as verbs, make either Imperative, Interrogative, or Declarative statement. There are no subclassifications of either Imperative or Interrogative statements.
Declarative statements have a "Mood" which is either Indicative or Subjunctive.
Either mood has several classifications which determine the "Tense" of the verb. Those classifications are:

- Present, Past, or Future
- Perfect or not Perfect
- Progressive or not Progressive
- a "Voice" which is either Active or Passive (The Passive Voice only exists for transitive verbs)

A verb that is neither Perfect nor Progressive is usually said to be Simple. Otherwise, they are usually said to be Perfect, Progressive, or Perfect and Progressive.
As far as I can tell, the term 'Indicative' is one of two moods, with the other being Subjunctive. Also, 'Preterite' is a term for what I would call the Simple Past Tense. Do I have those right?
My questions about the preferred terms I should be using are:

1. Is there another term for the classification of a verb into either Imperative, Interrogative, or Declarative statement?
2. Is there a better term than 'Not Perfect'?
3. Is there a better term than 'Not Progressive'?
4. Is there anything else I have missed out or it appears I need to know?

I am aware I have not mentioned Modal Verbs. I have a question or two about those but those can wait until after I get my terminology sorted out. :)

Comment: Here's a link you might find useful https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/378923/categories-of-verb-inflections; the terminology seems to be not quite standardized.

Comment: Thanks, @Xanne. At first look, the OP for that question was much more confused than I am now. But, I will wade through the answers and comments and will hopefully learn a few things. Still, answers from someone to my questions 1 to 3 in the OP would be helpful.

Comment: Since making the OP I have realised my description of the classifications of verbs omits the Interrogative. I have edited my OP to include my best guess of how that fits into things.

Comment: @Xanne, I've returned none the wiser after looking through that link. There were discussions there about whether the subjunctive mood even exists. It does, as in the example, "If I were a rich man." That has a valid meaning which not the same as, "If I was a rich man."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do the tenses and aspects in English correspond temporally to one another?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/how-do-the-tenses-and-aspects-in-english-correspond-temporally-to-one-another)